# Use Mongoose's findOneAndUpdate in Meteor

Tags: meteor, mongoose

I have a big problem with my meteor application. I need to use the findOneAndUpdate function in a Meteor app. I read the documentation, but i don't understand much, can we help me?

Comment: Meteor does not use Mongoose. Meteor uses its own [Mongo.Collection](https://devdocs.io/meteor/index#mongo_collection). Use `[YourCollection].update(selector, modifier)`

Comment: I think good use case for usage of findOneAndUpdate would be that it returns document before/after update depending on the setting. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Answer (score 0):

Hey meteor doesn't have FindOneAndUpdate function on Collection.
You can directly update.

```
Tasks.update(this._id, {
  $set: { checked: ! this.checked },
});

MyObject.update({findbyID or another variable}, {$set: {do the update}});
MyObject.update({id: objecid, private: true}, {$set: {private:false}});
```

Comment: I know that Meteor doesn't have FindOneAndUpdate Function. I need to manage the concurrency with update, i need to lock single document, and i found the function FindOneAndUpdate in MongoDB Documentation. I ask if there is a method to take this function in Meteor. thank you for reply!

Comment: @MarcoTribuzio When you do UPDATE with Meteor, it searches the specific document by id or whatever and then updates it.
MyObject.update({findbyID or another variable}, {$set: {do the update}});
MyObject.update({id: objecid, private: true}, {$set: {private:false}});